# Vaadin 14 - issue Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null

Tags: java, centos7, tomcat8, vaadin14

I have a Vaadin 14.7.5 application running fine on a CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core) VPS deployed on Tomcat 8.5.39 running Java 17+35-LTS-2724.

However when I deploy the same application to a newly created CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) VPS on Tomcat 8.5.39 or 8.5.72  running Java 17.0.2+8-LTS-86 I get the following error:

```
09-Mar-2022 10:44:27.899 SEVERE [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet [ServletStart]
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.vaadin.flow.di.Lookup.lookup(java.lang.Class)" because "lookup" is null
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileFromClassloader(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:341)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.getTokenFileContents(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:311)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.readBuildInfo(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:181)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.DeploymentConfigurationFactory.createInitParameters(DeploymentConfigurationFactory.java:174)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createDeploymentConfiguration(VaadinServlet.java:152)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.createServletService(VaadinServlet.java:190)
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.init(VaadinServlet.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:679)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on? The deployment itself runs fine, however on the first open of the webapplication I get this error in the localhost file.

Many thanks already for any given answer.

Regards,
Patrick